# Why does glob='*'; echo "$glob" write only a '*', and not a list of files?

Tags: bash, shell

My question is about the shell and globbing.

When doing something like :

```
myglob=*
echo $myglob
```

I get the file list of the directory, so it's ok

But when i do a :

```
myglob=*
echo "$myglob"
*
```

I got the * instead of the files in the directory.
What i don't understand, doesnt the shell pass the * to the echo command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doesnt the shell pass the * to the echo command ?

Yes, that's the problem.

`echo` just writes out what you pass it. If you pass it a `*` it will always just write out a `*`.

When you do

```
myglob=*
echo $myglob
```

Bash does **not** pass the `*`.

Instead, bash expands the glob first, and essentially rewrites the command into `echo file1 file2 file3 file4...`. Unsurprisingly, `echo` then writes `file1 file2 file3 file4...`.

Answer (score 1):

From [the bash manual page on double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

---

The second command evaluates to:

```
echo "*"
```

which, according to the link, does not expand.

Answer (score 1):

*doesnt the shell pass the * to the echo command ?*

Yes, when it is enclosed inside quotes. Filename expansion, *globbing*, is done by the shell during the line scan (not the `echo` command) but not when the pattern is inside quotes.

`set -x` (`xtrace`) is your friend, this shows the expansions and when they happen (the leading `+` is the `xtrace` prompt, `PS4`):

```
set -x
myglob=*
echo $myglob
```

Gives:

```
+ myglob='*'
+ echo ... filenames in the current directory ...
```

You can see that the expansion of `*` is done *before* `echo` is invoked.

Whereas:

```
set -x
myglob=*
echo "$myglob"
```

Gives:

```
+ myglob='*'
+ echo '*'
*
```

Here you can see there is no expansion, and that is one reason (there are others) for using quotes.

`set +x` will switch the `xtrace` feature off.